# Zoom blur effect in CSS or Javascript on text

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg-filters

I am wondering, if I can make something like a zoom blur effect in CSS thru custom filter. I want something like this: https://pixijs.io/pixi-filters/docs/PIXI.filters.ZoomBlurFilter.html. But I would like to apply it on the text. The best case (I image) is somethig like: `filter: url(zoom-blur.svg)`. But I do not know, if this filter can be made.

Comment: In theory, with a lot of work, I suppose you might be able to get a poor approximation of it using blur and a stack of displacement maps. But it would be very difficult to implement, and likely run slowly.  It would be a lot easier to implement using pixel operations on a `<canvas>` element.

Comment: Use Canvas - the SVG filter toolkit doesn't have the primitives to do this.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I would use it too, but my graphic designer wants this effect on <h1> text, so I need to apply it to the text itself :(. However, thanks for your answers.